# How to decode a JSON with array root in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, jsondecoder

I'm trying to parse some data i got from an api request. The problem is, none of the values have labels. i want to add labels to each value so i can reference the labels later in program.

```
struct dataSet : Codable {
    var variable1 : Int
    var variable2 : Double
    var variable3 : Double
    var variable4 : Double
    var variable5 : Double
    var variable6 : Double
    var variable7 : Double
    var variable8 : Int
}

struct firsBatch : Codable {
    var dataSet : [dataSet]
}

struct results : Codable {
    var firsBatch : firsBatch
    var last : Int
}

struct allData : Codable {
    var errors : [String]
    var results : results
}


//some api request code {...}


    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let parsedJSON = try decoder.decode(allData.self, from: data!)
        print(parsedJSON)
    } catch {
        print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

//Sample of data

> {"error":[],"results":{"firsBatch":[
>
> [21,"93423.5","324.5","21.0","63.0","1253.0","12.34",1],[42,"314.0","431.1","2341.0","67.1","6567.0","0.8754",4],[12,"4312.1","12.1","43.1","3432.1","0.0","123.432",0],[422,"23442.1","12.1","654.1","12.1","723.1","23.34521",1]
>
> ],"last":64274}}

Comment: `variables` should be `UpperCamelCase`. Every struct is simply a collection of variables, so it's a completely useless name.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `Variables`, not just a single `Variables` instance. So your decoding type should be `[Variables].self`, not `Variables.self`:

`let parsedJSON = try decoder.decode(variables.self, from: data!)`

Comment: I tried your solution but i got this error: JSON error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. I also updated the samples data to show the header and footer of the api data

Comment: @Liv Well you can't just ignore those lol. So you need to make another struct that holds `error: [SomeType]`, `results: DataSet`, `last: Int`

Comment: I updated the code but i still cant get it to work with these changes. the data is received in this format: {error[], result { firsBatch [dataSet], last } }